# Problema JQuery obtener valor de input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, base-de-datos

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
//Validar usuario existente con ajax
//Pedimos el valor del campo usuario para verificar si existe y enviarlo al controlador
//revise en la base de datos que esta palabra no exista
var usuarioExistente = false;
var emailExistente = false;

$("#usuarioRegistro").change(function(){
var usuario = $("#usuarioRegistro").val();
console.log('Usuario: ', usuario);
var datos = new FormData();
datos.append("validarUsuario", usuario);

$.ajax({
        url:"views/modules/ajax.php",
        method:"POST",
        data: datos,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(respuesta){
          console.log(respuesta);

        if (respuesta == 0) {

          $("label[for='usuarioRegistro'] span").html('<p>Este Usuario ya esxiste</p>');
            usuarioExistente = true;


        }else{
          $("label[for='usuarioRegistro'] span").html("<p>Correcto!</p>");
            usuarioExistente = false;
        }

      }

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>REGISTRO DE USUARIO</h1>

<form method="post"  onsubmit="return validarRegistro()">
 <label for="usuarioRegistro">Usuario<span></span></label>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Maximo 10 caracteres" maxlength="10" name="usuarioRegistro" id="usuarioRegistro" required>

 <label for="nombreCRegistro">Nombre Completo</label>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Maximo 30 caracteres" maxlength="30" name="nombreCRegistro" id="nombreCRegistro" required>

 <label for="passwordRegistro">Contraseña</label>
 <input type="password" placeholder="Minimo 6 caracteres, incluir numeros y mayusculas" name="passwordRegistro" id="passwordRegistro" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}" required>

 <label for="rpasswordRegistro">Repita la Contraseña</label>
 <input type="password" placeholder="Minimo 6 caracteres, incluir numeros y mayusculas" name="rpasswordRegistro" id="rpasswordRegistro" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}" required>

 <label for="emailRegistro">Correo Electrónico<span></span> </label>
 <input type="email" placeholder="Escriba su correo electrónico correctamente" name="emailRegistro" id="emailRegistro" required>

 <p style="text-align:center"> <a href="#"></a> Al hacer click en Enviar Acepta los terminos y condiciones</p>

 <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Enviar">

</form>
```

Intento tomar el valor del campo input con id="usuarioRegistro" pero no lo toma.

Ya tengo la libreria, intento mostrar el valor por consola pero no funciona.
Probando el código aquí en la página si lo toma es lo que no entiendo.

Utilizo Chrome.

Comment: ¿Simplemente no te lo muestra o genera algún error? Si este fuera el caso, ¿qué error?

Comment: Intentalo asi: `$("#usuarioRegistro").on("change", function(){`

Comment: Error ninguno, solo no me lo muestra por lo tanto no puedo hacer que la funcion se ejecute.

Comment: Lo raro es que aquí si que funciona correctamente. Es posible que la caché todavía no se haya refrescado. Prueba a ejecutar la web en una ventana de incógnito a ver que pasa.

Comment: No funciona en modo incognito. Ya he utilizado otras versiones de la JQuery y nada

Comment: Asegurate que el elemento `<input>` este antes que el `<script>` en la estructura del html y que jquery se importa antes que tu script. es una posible razon por la cual funciona aqui y no en el ejemplo local. la otra un typo.

Comment: No Funciona. Tengo el JQuery en primer lugar en el Template y el formulario lo llamo con un include que contiene toda la navegacion de la web.

Comment: Estoy contruyendo el sitio en MVC para tenerlo mejor estructurado. no se si eso afecta en algo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Donde tienes definido tu código js? creo te falta meter tu script dentro de esta sección.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
//aquí pon tu código js
});
```

Comment: Se la agregue y sigo sin poder ver el valor.

Comment: Que te marca si pones esto?  alert($("#usuarioRegistro").val());

Comment: Ningun error. simplemente introduzco un nombre y deberia mostrarlo en consola pero nada

Comment: Gracias al parecer me hacia falta lo que me digiste al principio solo que habia cambiado el change por on en pruebas anteriores. Funcionando Gracias